# A question on classification of quadratic polynomials in even characteristic

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, finite-fields, power-series

$\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}$Let $f_1,...,f_n \in \bar{\mathbb{F}}_2[x_1,...,x_n]$ such that $f_i = x_i + q_i$ for $1\leq i \leq n-1$ and $f_n = q_n$ where $q_1,...,q_n$ are homogenous quadratic polynomials. Suppose $x_n^{2^r} \in \bar{\mathbb{F}}_2[[f_1,...,f_n]]$ then I conjecture that there exists a path $i_1,...,i_k$ such that $i_k = n$ and $x_{i_1}^2 \in \supp(q_n)$ and $x_{i_j}^2 \in \supp(q_{i_{j-1}})$ for $2 \leq j \leq k$.

$r = 1$ would imply $x_n^2 \in \supp(q_n)$ and we can also show for $r=2,3$ that a path of length $\leq r$ of the form specified above exists. For large r, I expect this to be true but am falling into technical difficulties.

My approach till now has been to first show that $x_n^2 \in \supp(q_i)$ for some i and  by setting $x_1=x_2= ... = x_{n-1} = 0$ and then continue this style of argument ahead. But this argument breaks down soon, so I hope to use some monomial ordering argument to prove the conjecture but can't see how to use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $f_i=x_i+x_4^2$ for $i=1,2,3$ and $f_4=x_1x_2+x_2x_3+x_3x_1$. Then $x_4^4=f_1f_2+f_2f_3+f_3f_1+f_4$, but no $x_i^2$ lies in the support of $f_4$.

Comment: This is a good counter-example, what I had in mind was to clear $x_4^2$ from $f_2, f_3$ and rename $x_1 + x_2 , x_1 + x_3$ as $x_2,x_3$, and then we start observing the above phenomenon. I am not being able to express this idea formally.